# How to identify text that appears only occasionally in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I find text that appears on the page sometimes? A typical example is a wrong password. Then a message will appear stating that the password has been entered incorrectly and I need to make an assertion for this message. The message appears in this block `<td colspan = "2" style = "color: Red;" align = "center"> Wrong name or password.</td>.` Unfortunately, the code I enter using xpath will not find my text.

see:

```
wait = WebDriverWait (driver 10)
text_tag = wait.until (EC.presence_of_element_located ((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b")))

if text_tag:
    assert text_tag.text == "Incorrect name or password."
    print (text_tag.text)
    print ("Found - OK")
else:
    exit()
```

Comment: In your `xpath` you are trying to find `<b>` element while target text is present inside `<td>` tag as you have given.

Comment: if you are unable to find element using `xpath` try `td[style = 'color: Red;']` `cssSelector`, may be it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks for help. This is final script which is function. It was necessary change XPATH to CSS selector:

```
error_message = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td[style = "color: Red;"]')

if error_message:
    assert error_message.text == "Incorrect name or password."
    print (error_message.text)
    print ("Found - OK")
else:
    exit()
    print("Not FOUND")

driver.implicitly_wait(0)
```

Comment: setting the implicit wait to zero does nothing here.  zero is the default, and you do no actions after setting it anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can set temporary implicit wait instead of `WebDriverWait` and check if the element exist using `find_elements`. This will look for the element up to 10 seconds, and if the element exist the returned list won't be empty.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

error_message = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(., "Incorrect name or password")]')
if error_message:
    assert error_message[0].text == "Incorrect name or password."
    print (text_tag.text)
    print ("Found - OK")

driver.implicitly_wait(0)
```

As a side note, don't use absolute `xpath` `/html/body/...`, it makes fragile locator.

Comment: Thanks for help, but the test ends with Process finished with exit code 0. But not with Found - OK...
The second thing... do you know some converter for xpath, where is posible change it to relative xpath..

Comment: @Tomasito I don't know any converter, but Iin my answer there is an example. What is the actual text? `Wrong name or password` or `Incorrect name or password`? there is a big difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    text_tag =wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located("Xpath"))
    if text_tag:
        assert text_tag.text == "Incorrect name or password."
        print (text_tag.text)
        print("Found - OK")
    else:
        exit()
except:
    exit()
    print("Not FOUND")
```

Comment: No, this not function. The test always ends without finding the text.